# prevent request/response getting tracked between android app and remote server

Tags: android, ssl, fiddler

I have android app for which data is getting fetched from remote server. How do I prevent the request/response between android app and remote server getting tracked through tools like fiddler by any hacker. Please suggest me the techniques to do the same. I am not using any SSL for communicating between app and remote server.

Comment: Use SSL; there is no way to prevent tools like WireShark listening on a computer, and the device connecting through that computer (as a proxy) to the internet.